# Count within two columns with a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data as follows:

```
Name|  Place|   TS
   A|     AA|   12/25/2017 0:00
   A|     AA|   12/31/2017 0:00
   A|     AA|   1/10/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   1/15/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   1/31/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   2/3/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   2/5/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   2/7/2018 0:00
   A|     AA|   2/8/2018 0:00
   A|     BB|   1/1/2018 0:00
   A|     BB|   1/22/2018 0:00
   A|     BB|   2/5/2018 0:00
```

What I need to accomplish here is to count how many times one person visited one place within certain days. For example, person A visited place AA 4 times in 7 days and place BB 1 time (count from today). My expected outcome should look like below:

```
Name    Place   Last_Week   Last_Month
A       AA      4           7
A       BB      1           2
```

Below is what I currently have but I have a hard time to aggregate the counts with the condition. Please help and thank you so much.

```
SELECT
  Name, Place, COUNT(*)
FROM
  SampleTable
GROUP BY
  Name, Place, TS
HAVING
  TS >= now()::date - 7
ORDER BY
  Name, Place;
```

Comment: Your `HAVING` statement does not make any sense. `HAVING` is **post**-aggregation filtering. What you need here is a ***conditional aggregation*** normally handled via `CASE WHEN` constructs as a parameter to aggregate function.

Comment: @PM77-1, `HAVING` is my weakest part and I have to admit that I don't understand that. And also thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group your data by name and place, then count how many time the dates fit in your constraint

```
 select
    name,
    place,
    sum(case when lw.TS >= now()::date - 7 then 1 else 0 end) last_week,
    sum(case when lw.TS >= now()::date - 30 then 1 else 0 end) last_month
    from sampleTable st
    GROUP BY
      Name, Place
    order by name, place
```

Comment: good. One comma to remove before the "from" and one before the "order"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use FILTER:

```
select
name,
place,
count(*) filter (where TS >= now()::date - 7) last_week,
count(*) filter (where TS >= now()::date - 30) last_month
from sampleTable group by name, place order by name, place
```

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

Comment: Wow, this is another cool way. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.